# Calling str() on a Django model with only a __unicode__ method returns different encoding for special characters

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

When calling `str()` on a Django model object with special characters in the returned field, in this case the character **é** it will be returned as `\xc3\xa9` instead as the expected `\xe9`. What is the problem?

I'm using Django 1.5.1 and `#coding=utf-8` and `from __future__ import unicode_literals` as [recommended in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling).

I have only implemented the `__unicode__` method and not a `__str__` method as [Django will use the `__unicode__` method when calling `str()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode).

Here's a code example (not the real production code).

tests.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.test import TestCase
from unicodebug.models import MyModel


class TestMyModel(TestCase):
    def test_mymodel_str(self):
        mymodel = MyModel(name='Chéri')
        self.assertEqual(str(mymodel), 'Chéri')

    def test_mymodel_unicode(self):
        mymodel = MyModel(name='Chéri')
        self.assertEqual(unicode(mymodel), 'Chéri') #  using unicode() works fine!
```

models.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Output in terminal when running the test.

```
(venv)frecon test$ python manage.py test unicodebug
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py:501: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if not first == second:

F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_mymodel_str (unicodebug.tests.TestMyModel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicodebug/tests.py", line 10, in test_mymodel_str
    self.assertEqual(str(mymodel), 'Chéri')
AssertionError: 'Ch\xc3\xa9ri' != u'Ch\xe9ri'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: Do you fully understand what `str()` *does*?

Comment: Also, looks like you set the `sys.defaultencoding` value; that's generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str()` has to *encode* the unicode value to produce a Pyton byte string, it'll do so with the default encoding (`sys.defaultencoding`). You must have set the latter to `UTF8` explicitly, because by default that is set to `ASCII`.

What you see is the UTF-8 encoding for the Unicode value your model returned. If you want your test to pass, you'd have to *decode* that value to match the Unicode value you are comparing it with, or *encode* the other value:

```
self.assertEqual(str(mymodel), 'Chéri'.encode('utf8'))
```

or

```
self.assertEqual(str(mymodel).decode('utf8'), 'Chéri')
```

Short demo:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> b'Ch\xc3\xa9ri' == 'Chéri'.encode('utf8')
True
>>> b'Ch\xc3\xa9ri'.decode('utf8') == 'Chéri'
True
```

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder